# Delegate method in the first view does not get invoked from the second view

Tags: ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

In a view, let's call it firstView I created a secondView as follows and pushed it if certain thing happened in the firstView:

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
    [secondVC release];
```

Now when I'm in the secondView if let say a button is pressed I want to go back to firstView and also pass back a value from secondView to the firstView (let say an integer value of a textfield from secondView to the firstView).

Here is what I tried:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate;

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "firstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *xInput;
    id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

- (IBAction)useXPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (assign) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (retain) IBOutlet UITextField *xInput;

@end

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)sender xValue:(int)value;

@end
```

And in the m file

```
- (IBAction)useXPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.delegate secondViewController:self xValue:1234]; // 1234 is just for test
}
```

And then in the firstView I did:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate> {

}

@end
```

And implemented:

```
- (void) secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)sender xValue:(int)value
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now, the problem is for one in FirstViewController I get the warning that "No definition of protocol "SecondViewControllerDelegate" is found, and for two the delegate method (last piece of code above) does not get invoked at all. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure delegate != nil?

Comment: What is it that I should have done and where to make sure the delegate is not nil?

Comment: Did you set your delegate? like secondVC.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Add

```
secondVC.delegate = self;
```

Also instead of

```
- (void) secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)sender xValue:(int)value
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You should use

```
- (void) secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)sender xValue:(int)value
{
    [sender popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Omar Abdelhafith! Setting the delegate was indeed the solution.

Comment: If there is a ZerothViewController that presented FirstViewController modally how would that change setting the delegate. Basically I want SecondViewController to pass the data to ZerothViewController but I couldn't figure out the correct statement. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

In `FirstViewController` .h file :

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate> {

SecondViewController *secondViewController;

}

@end
```

In implementation file , where you init SecondViewController instance next line assign self to delegate property :

```
secondViewController.delegate = self;
```

Next define delegate method :

```
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)sender xValue:(int)value
{
NSLog ("This is a Second View Controller with value %i",value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mancunianetz! I wish I could select more of these as a correct answer. What you said was indeed the solution. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1: The `@protocol` definition for `SecondViewControllerDelegate` looks like it's in `secondViewController.h`; are you sure this file is imported in `firstViewController.h`? Otherwise it won't know about the protocol.

Problem 2: It might be totally unrelated to problem 1. Are you sure the action is hooked up properly? Can you put a `NSLog()` call in your `useXPressed:` to make sure that method is actually getting called when you expect it to?

Comment: Problem 1: Yes, SecondViewController is imported in the FirstViewController. Problem 2: I put a break point and yes the program goes into useXPressed: but does not go into - (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)sender xValue:(int)value; since I put a break point there too.